# block port while its already being used?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ufw

let's say I have a program running that is already using a random tcp/udp port. If I deny connections now via iptables/ufw the port is still open for that programm until I close/reopen it. Is there any way to block the traffic without restarting that programm?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -I OUTPUT [-d DEST_IP] -p tcp -m tcp --dport PORT_NUMBER -j DROP
```

Will stop the application from communicating on that port completely. The fact that the port is still open doesn't really mean anything - it will eventually get closed by timeout.

Comment: Thats what I tried but it doesn't seem to work. I even tried apache as a test application but if do that with port 80/443 the web server is still accessible until I restart the service.

Comment: I've just double checked it and the rule effectively breaks the connection, i.e. the traffic stops completely. Maybe you're `-A` adding it, instead of `-I` inserting it. **If any preceding rules allow the traffic to flow, your extra rules will not have any effect**.

Comment: Okay my bad, thanks for helping out its working now! :)